# Efficiently join (and update) a table by value into a min/max value range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables that look like this:

```
                  IpNumbers
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|____min___|____max___|__correspondingCountry_|
|          |          |                       |
|    0     |   10     |       Australia       |
|    11    |   20     |           US          |
|    21    |   30     |         Taiwan        |
|____31____|___40_____|_________Canada________|



                  Users
+----------+----------+----------------+
|__userId__|__ipNumber__|____country___|
|    1     |      6     |              |
|    2     |     13     |              |
|    3     |      7     |              |
|____4_____|_____21_____|______________|
```

There are IpNumbers table which has a number derrived from an IP address - and this corresponds to a certain country the IP address belongs to. If the Ip Number is between `11 and 20` for example then the user with that IP Address is from the United States (US).

My problem: I have about 60,000 users in the `Users` table - each users has an IP number associated with them. I also have the IpNumbers table with about 4,000,000 records of Ip Number vs Country in it.

What is the most efficient SQL query I could construct to assign a Country to each user in the `Users` table? And how long could I expect the query to be completed in?

Note: I have indexed `min` and `max` columns in the `ipNumbers` table and I have also indexed `userId` column in the `Users` table. The `userId` field is also unique.

Edit: The ipNumber in the `users` table is also the derived integer value

Comment: Is the `ipNumber` column in `Users` also the derived integer value, or is it an IPv4 dotted quad 1.2.3.4?  Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output for both of the tables.

Comment: And do I understand that you want to store the country directly with each user, rather than query it at runtime based on the user's `ipNumber` value? That results in a denormalization.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - yes the ipNumber in the users table is also the derived integer number. And yes - I'd like to store each country directly with each users. This query won't be run at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather common problem.  I think the best approach starts with an index on `IpNumbers(min, max, corresponding_country)`.  (The last column is not strictly necessary).

Then, you can use the following query:

```
select u.*,
       (select ipn.corresponding_country
        from IpNumbers ipn
        where ipn.min <= u.ipNumber
        order by ipn.min desc
        limit 1
       ) as corresponding_country
from users u;
```

This should use the index for the `where` and the `order by`.  However, it does not validate the end condition.  If you need, you can use the same logic to get `max` out and then do a comparison to see if the ip address falls in the range.

Comment: @user2864740 . . You can try using the additional constraint `and ipn.max <= u.ipNumber`.  I must've found, at some point, that that impedes the use of the index.  But, if it works then use it!

Comment: I'm so spoiled by [not MySQL] that I often forget the details relating to the specific context :}

Comment: is it u.ipNumber >= ipn.min order by ipn.min limit1? i m confused about min >= ipNumber, why min >= ipNumber?

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke . . . I think you are right.  I changed the logic to a `<=` along with reversing the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
SELECT u.USERID, u.IPNUMBER, i.CorrespondingCOUNTRY FROM USERS u, IPNUMBERS i
WHERE u.IPNUMBER BETWEEN i.MIN AND i.MAX
/
```